# using zero-one-inflated beta regression (zoib) to fit probability response data with an interaction and a single random term in R

Tags: r, probability, percentage

I am trying to fit a `zoib` model with occupancy probability as the response variable against the interaction between household income and a categorical variable, diet (e.g. insectivore, granivore) and using species as a random term. This is to explore if the relationship of species occupancy probability in an area with household income of the area differs depending on the species foraging guild/diet category. I am using `zoib` because I have percentage data and because my data is one and zero inflated.

I am not confident using `zoib` or beta-regression and have reached out to the author of the `zoib` package to provide me with the correct way to fit the model.

This is the structure of the data I am using:

```r
'data.frame':   242 obs. of  6 variables:
 $ pentad     : chr  "2350_2940" "2350_2945" "2350_3015" "2355_2920"
 $ species    : chr  "Common Ostrich" "Common Ostrich" "Common Ostrich"
 $ occupancy  : num  1 0.1717 0.2012 0.0445 1 ...
 $ Diet       : chr  "HerbiGrani" "HerbiGrani" "HerbiGrani" "HerbiGrani"
 $ urban.cover: num  39.1 31.1 25.4 21.7 32.3 ...
 $ meanInc    : num  73470 33968 81768 124308 277171
```

Here is the code I was provided with:

```
m1 <- zoib(occupancy ~ meanInc*Diet|1|meanInc*Diet|1, random = 1,    
       EUID = OPdat$species,  zero.inflation = TRUE,  
       one.inflation = TRUE, data = OPdat,   n.iter=50, 
       n.thin=20, n.burn=50)
```

This is the error I get:

> Error in joint.1z01(y, n, q, xmu.1, p.xmu, xsum.1, p.xsum, x0.1, p.x0,  :
> object 'x1.1' not found"

The `zoib` rjournal is for me quite difficult to understand. Can anyone help me understand this error? what is the object x1.1? Any other suggestions/packages to fit this model would also be appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We could really use a [mcve]. Are you using the `zoib` package?  What code are you running?  At the very least, can we see a `summary()` of your input data and the code you are running to fit the model?

Comment: @BenBolker Thank you. I have edited the post with your suggestions

Comment: This is much better but we probably still need a [mcve] ...

Answer (score 1):

From the "Details" section of `?zoib::zoib`:

> On the right side of the formula, it can include up to 5 parts in
> the following order: xb | xd | x0 | x1 | z, where xb represents
> the fixed-effects covariates/factors in the link function of the
> mean of the beta distribution, xd represents the fixed-effects
> covariates/factors in the link function of the sum of the two
> shape parameters of the beta distribution, x0 represents the
> fixed-effect covariates/factors in the link function of Pr(y=0),
> x1 represents the fixed-effect covariates/factors in the link
> function of Pr(y=1|y>0), and z represents the random-effect
> covariates/factors.

Related: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/494369/how-to-fit-a-zoib-regression-model-with-random-effects-from-zoib-package

I'm *guessing* that you need another `|1` at the end of your RHS, i.e.
`meanInc*Diet|1|meanInc*Diet|1|1`, so that you are specifying:

- conditional mean model: `meanInc*Diet`
- dispersion model: `1` (trivial/constant)
- zero-inflation model: `meanInc*Diet`
- one-inflation model: `1` (trivial/constant)
- random-effect model: `1` (varying-intercept) [this is the part I added]

I believe the `brms` package will also fit ZOIB/Z01B models.